# Django ORM model to sync with db record changed by external

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

In Django model, is there anyway for instant sync of loaded model object with db records updated by external?

Here is sample scenario.

1. I load record in Django model by get method.

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
print(book.title) # It will print '21 century'
```

2. I update relevant db data manually in database using query in PGAdmin

```
update book set title='22 century' where id=1
```

3. the model obj loaded in 1st step still retains old data instead of latest update from 2 step

```
print(book.title) # It still print '21 century' instead of '22 century'
```

I have no solution yet and need help for this

Comment: It can be done using [PostgreSQL notifications](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) but it's not trivial, and not recommended. It is generally safer not to hold on to an object for that long. You may also consider locking the row or the table until you are done so that no external process can modify it.

Comment: Thanks. but I recall instant sync approach of SQLAlchemy. Is there relevant way in Django?

Comment: I don't think SQLAlchemy does it any different than Django. The ORM has no way of knowing if the underlying data has changed, other than fetching the same data every time you access a property. You can simulate the same by calling `book.refresh_from_db()` before you `print(book.title)` (even then there is a chance of a race condition).

Comment: Gotcha, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks @Selcuk